# How to say "Not an Object" in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class, Issue, that should only perform its logic if a file's name is a certain format:

```
namespace Site.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        String FilePath { get; set; }
        String FileName { get; set; }
        String HTML {get; set;}

        public Issue(String path)
        {
            FilePath = path;
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);

            if(FileName.StartsWith(".")){
                // How do I say "Not an Issue; don't continue logic"
            }

            HTML = "<li>" + FileName + "</li>;
        }
    }
}
```

I could put all the logic in an else, but I'd really like to avoid unnecessary conditions if possible. Also, I'm curious if there is a way to do this.

Comment: `if(!FileName.StartsWith(".")`?

Comment: Use Regex to check for the right pattern

Comment: just use a return statement                                                return;

Comment: and don't forget to close bracket if(FileName.StartsWith("."))

Comment: @Rhumborl I'd like to avoid putting all the logic in an if. This example is a simplification, the actual logic has a lot more moving parts. Also I'm curious if there is a way to do it.

Comment: I thought he meant he is looking for a way to check for certain formats in file name, so using regex lets him avoid multiple hard coded if else statements!

Comment: else statement, return statement, throw exception

Comment: Wow, a lotta hate for this question. What should I have done instead of asking SO?

Comment: @TravisHeeter, lack of research I presume. This question is highly unlikely to be useful for anybody else. Down-voting is not *hate*, it's a statistical tool to mark question as *not-so good*.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for the response. I did some Google searches, couldn't find any answers. I thought it would be a good question, and am surprised by the downvotes considering there's 5 different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of performing the validation logic in the constructor you will want to move it to some form of factory method and perform the check there.

```
namespace Site.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        String FilePath { get; set; }
        String FileName { get; set; }
        String HTML { get; set; }

        private Issue(String path)
        {
            FilePath = path;
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            HTML = "<li>" + FileName + "</li>;
        }

        public static Issue CreateIssue(String path)
        {

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

            if (fileName.StartsWith("."){
                 throw new Exception("Not an issue");
                // or you could return null and handle that in the calling code
            }

            return new Issue(path);

        }
    }
}
```

then instead of calling `new Issue(path)` you now call `Issue.CreateIssue(path)` and catch the exception or check for null return.

**EDIT** : added missing return type

Comment: +1 for a factory (you forgot to add the return type)

Comment: woops, fixed now.. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How exactly would a factory pattern help here?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way in C# to refrain from constructing an object once you've entered the constructor.

You can of course return from the method and not execute the remaining code, but all this will give you is an object which is most likely not in a useful state. Another option is to throw an exception, but this should be reserved for exceptional situations, as your program will otherwise quickly devolve into a mess of try catch based flow control.

Generally, you don't want to call a constructor without doing basic validation ensuring that the construction will succeed first. If this is a common operation you can make a factory method for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing parenthesis on the if statement, put an exclamation point to check for false.

```
if (!FileName.StartsWith(".")) {
    HTML = "<li>" + FileName + "</li>;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid putting all the logic in an if. This example is a simplification, the actual logic has a lot more moving parts. Also I'm curious if there is a way to do it.

Comment: @TravisHeeter I really don't get what you're trying to do... you're trying to do what's in this answer in a different way? I don't know much about C# but maybe you could use `?:`?

Comment: I'm sending in a file path. It should perform the logic to pdfs, but there's a lot of crap in the folder that has the same name as a real pdf, but starts with '._', I want to ignore those files.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Then this is your best choice unless you're willing to do stuff outside this class ;) **Edit:** I think the accepted answer is a good choice, actually

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly solution, using exceptions to stop your logic:

```
public class Issue
    {
        String FilePath { get; set; }
        String FileName { get; set; }
        String HTML {get; set;}

        Exception NotIssueException;

        public Issue(String path)
        {
            NotIssueException = new Exception("Not an Issue Exception");
            FilePath = path;
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);

            if(!FileName.StartsWith("."))
            {
                throw NotIssueException;
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Your Logic
            }

            HTML = "<li>" + FileName + "</li>;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use Try\Catch blocks to manage this exception.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a static method inside Issue to create an instance of Issue?

```
namespace Site.Models
{
public class Issue
{
    String FilePath { get; set; }
    String FileName { get; set; }
    String HTML {get; set;}

    public Issue(String filename)
    {
        HTML = "<li>" + FileName + "</li>;
    }

    public static Issue getIssue(String path)
    {
        FilePath = path;
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);

        if(!FileName.StartsWith("."){
            return new Issue(FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            //throw exception or whatever you want to do to handle it
        }
     }
}
}
```